# How to pass a token to my action for login a user?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to implement redux toolkit to my app but i dont know how to verify is my login reducer is working or not as i log in with a user:

This is my login component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { loginUser } from '../reducers/auth/authSlice';

//Material UI
import {Grid, Container, Box, Button, FormControl, InputLabel, Input, FormHelperText } from '@mui/material'

function Login() {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ 
    email: '',
    password: ''
    
  });

  const { email, password } = formData;

  const onChange = e => setFormData({
      ...formData, [e.target.name]:e.target.value
  });

  const onSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(loginUser(email,password))
    
  }


    return (
    <Container>
        <Box p={4}>
            <Grid container  >
                <form onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)} >
                    <Grid item md={12}>
                        <FormControl>
                            <InputLabel htmlFor="email">Email</InputLabel>
                            <Input 
                            id='email' 
                            type='email' 
                            name='email'
                            value={email}
                            onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                            />
                            <FormHelperText>Insert your email</FormHelperText>
                        </FormControl>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item md={12}>    
                        <FormControl>
                            <InputLabel htmlFor="password">Password</InputLabel>
                            <Input 
                            id="password" 
                            type='password' 
                            name='password'
                            value={password}
                            onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                            />
                            <FormHelperText>Insert your password (must have at least 6 characters)</FormHelperText>
                        </FormControl>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item md={12}>    
                        <Button type='submit' variant="contained" color="primary">
                            Login
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </form>
            </Grid>
        </Box>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default Login
```

And this is my reducer:
If you can see in my loginUser and loadUser i think i am not passing the response to any part of my code because the console shows an empty array after i submit the form.

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

import setAuthToken from '../../utils/setAuthToken';

import axios from 'axios';

const initialState = {
    token: localStorage.getItem('item'),
    isAuthenticated: null,
    loading: true,
    user: null,
    error: null
}

export const loadUser = createAsyncThunk(
  'user/loadUser',
  async ({ rejectWithValue }) => {

    if(localStorage.token){
      setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
    }

    try {
      const res = axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/auth');
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
    }
  }
)

export const registerUser = createAsyncThunk(
  'user/registerUser',
  async (newUser, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      };
      const body = JSON.stringify(newUser);
      const response = await axios.post(
        'http://localhost:3000/api/users',
        body,
        config
      );
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
    }
  }
);


export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk('auth/login', async ({ email, password }, { dispatch, rejectWithValue }) => {
  const body = { email, password };

  try {
    const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/auth', body);

    dispatch(loadUser());

    return res.data;
  } catch (err) {
    return rejectWithValue(err.response.data);
  }
});

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [registerUser.pending]: (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
      state.error = null;
    },
    [registerUser.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.user = action.payload;
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = null;
    },
    [registerUser.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.payload;
    },
    [loadUser.pending]: (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
      state.error = null;
    },
    [loadUser.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.isAuthenticated = true;
      state.user = action.payload;
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = false;
    },
    [loadUser.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.isAuthenticated = false;
      state.error = action.payload;

    },
    [loginUser.pending]: (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
      state.error = null;
    },
    [loginUser.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.token = localStorage.setItem('token')
      state.isAuthenticated = true;
      state.loading = false;
      state.user = action.payload;
    },
    [loginUser.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.isAuthenticated = false;
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.payload;
    }
  }
})

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const {  } = userSlice.actions


export default userSlice.reducer
```

Where can i check if my log in was successfull? Where should i console log or where should i validate the variable of isAuthenticated?

Comment: Are you using the Logger for Redux? The [Redux docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore#full-example) present an example of how to set it up. More details are on the [Logger for Redux](https://github.com/LogRocket/redux-logger#logger-for-redux) GitHub.